# Alpine.js x-model does not work with x-for

Tags: javascript, frontend, alpine.js

I'm trying to use the Input type=number TAG to dynamically determine how many iterations the x-for should go through.

My Problem: If I change the counter, the x-for only goes through one iteration. Regardless of what the counter says.

Here is my Code:

```
<div x-data="{player_count: 2}">
    <span class="text-3xl mr-48">Player Count:</span>
    <input x-model="player_count" id="player_count" name="player_count"/>

    <template x-for="i in player_count">
        <div x-text="i"></div>
    </template>
</div>
```

Thanks for any kind of help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. You have to explicitly tell the x-model to store an int...

```
x-model.number="player_count"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).